# Cannot navigate directly to website hosted on s3 + cloudfront

Tags: amazon-s3

I have a site hosted on AWS S3 + Cloudfront. I am able to access it just fine if I navigate to `https://mysamplesite.com`. However, navigate directly to `https://mysamplesite.com/some_link`, I get a 403 error:

```
<Error>
    <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
    <Message>Access Denied</Message>
    <RequestId>DB93462807BAEBCE</RequestId>
    <HostId>MSGCoilI76PVfdpFFEuabJ/bdc0lvdIhGZqzabrlcKMUQifBwu37RtoA32mvy3BmD/OPK0WlG70=</HostId>
</Error>
```

[image: Error screenshot]

However, it works fine if I access `https://mysamplesite.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/some_link`

Does anyone know what configuration I need to fix?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The browser error screen usually shows where it went wrong. Something as below. Did you see anything?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/QOTdp.png

Comment: Yep! I updated my question with a screenshot of the error in the browser

Comment: S3 Static web hosting, are both `Index document` and `Error document` set to home page let's say index.html ?